# Does Django automatically create indexes?

Tags: python, sql, django, database, postgresql

I'm working on a Django project using Postgresql as an attached database. I've noticed that some queries took a very long time and even found that I had over a dozen indexes on many different fields in my database, some that I've deemed unnecessary.

My plan is to remove the ones I do not need but I'm interested to know if Django does this in a "smart" way when creating models or there is some default mechanism in place for creating indexes that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Django does create indexes automatically for some fields. For example it is stated in the documentation for [Foreign Keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> A database index is automatically created on the **ForeignKey**. You
> can disable this by setting **db_index** to **False**.

Also when you set [`unique`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) to `True` on a field:

> Note that when unique is True, you don’t need to specify db_index,
> because unique implies the creation of an index.

Also on a [`SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield):

> Implies setting Field.db_index to True.

On a field level you can control whether a field has an index or not by passing the [`db_index`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) argument to the field.

You can also specify the [`indexes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#indexes) option in the models `Meta`:

```
class MyModel(model.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['field1', 'field2'], name='some_idx'),
        ]
```

Comment: Is it best practice to have an index for each foreign key in my database?

Comment: @ThatcherThornberry that totally depends on your need. If you see the documentation on Foreign Keys that I have linked it also states that _"You may want to avoid the overhead of an index if you are creating a foreign key for consistency rather than joins, or if you will be creating an alternative index like a partial or multiple column index."_

Comment: is this meta option will create indexing on individual fields or joint index ?

Comment: @DeepanshuMehta there will be an index created for each instance of `Index` in the list `indexes`. So for the given example it creates one multi-column index on the fields 'field1' and 'field2'. You can read the linked documentation (which also further links to [Model index reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/indexes/#module-django.db.models.indexes)) for more info.